# Database.upsert passes when operation is done via System admin, but fails with other profile

Tags: apex, workflow, exception

I am doing a database.upsert in the finish method of my batch. Now when logged in as System admin, it does not give any error. But when logged in as another profile in my org. It gives the following error:

**duplicate value found: UniqueKey__c duplicates value on record with id**

The UniqueKey__c has an external ID checked and is Unique checked.
I have even checked the UniqueKey__c is different for all the opportunity products which are getting inserted.

And is populated by a workflow.

```
    List<Database.upsertResult> resultList= Database.upsert(listOLIstoUpdate,false);
        for(Integer i = 0; i<listOLIstoUpdate.size(); i++){
            Database.upsertResult sr = resultList[i];           
            if(!sr.success) {
                for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                    system.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                    system.debug('fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could it be possible that the duplicate is in the list of records you are upserting?

Comment: batch always runs in system mode. It doesn't matter who is the logged in user. Are you sure you are getting this error in batch.

Comment: @Eric I have inserted System.debug and checked the uniqueKey__c is unique for all the Opportunity product.

Comment: The above snippet is from finish method, so i am sure that error is coming here only.

Comment: And you're sure it upserts identical data set or are they different? You're using the default version of upsert (by salesforce Id). What happens if you'll do it by your ext id? `Database.upsert(myRecords, MySobject__c.fields.External_ID__c, false);`? I suspect it has something to do with sharing issues... Can you temporarily grant this user right to "view all" on the object and see if it fixes the error?

Comment: there is another unique key field in the same object, which is passed as null. Will NULL be treated as duplicate?

Comment: @eyescream I had tried using this earlier as `Schema.SObjectField f = OpportunityLineItem.UniqueKey__c;` and passing as `List<Database.upsertResult> resultList= Database.upsert(listOLIstoUpdate, f,false);` but  it threw an error that Missing Unique key.

Comment: What if you try the regular version, not "Database"? `upsert listOLIstoUpdate UniqueKey__c;` - just the field name like that. Comment out the error finding, if it'll throw an error it'll just throw (wrap it in try-catch if you have to but might be good to see if that's the only error you're experiencing or maybe something else lurks there).

Answer (score 0):

When you are 100% positive that your upsert isn't clashing against existing objects, check if you don't insert more than one new Object at a time (in one batch).

Also review the Workflow which populates UniqueKey__c. If behavior differs between Admin and others, different UniqueKey__c-calculation seems likely.

To debug turn the unique restriction off temporarily e.g. in a full/partial Sandbox. Then check for the new records UniqueKey__c values.

Another way to debug which sounds crazy but is working better and better for me to send Emails to myself containg serialized complex object data of full maps or lists. Creeping through console logs is simply too slow. The email trick works nearly everwhere. But you need to be careful that all your data is serializable.

Comment: Error : `duplicate value found: UniqueKey__c duplicates value on record with id` means only UniqueKey__c field is getting duplicated somehow right? Or should I check for other fields too?